# When I upgrade to Rails 7.1, I get a warning that "ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.runtime= is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

When I upgraded the Rails app I am developing to 7.1, I got the following warning.

The problem is occurring in the part where ActiveRecord is used to access the DB.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.runtime is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.2.
```

It will be removed starting with 7.2, so I don't think it is currently a problem, but is there anything I can do to fix it now?

I can hide the logs, but this is not a fundamental solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to understand if this warning comes from Rails code, a gem, or your code. There should be a line below saying where it came from. If it's from Rails itself, then I'm sure it will be fixed before 7.2 release.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Probably, this warning comes from Rails.
I'll ignore it for now.